# problems configuring Mysql on ubuntu for remote access

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

Every thing works ok localy, but having som issues connecting remotely, the user is granted remote access ao it shold be ok.

the machine awnser from the client machine

```
W:\>ping 148.140.26.121

Pinger 148.140.26.121 med 32 byte data:

Svar fra 148.140.26.121: byte=32 tid=4ms TTL=64
Svar fra 148.140.26.121: byte=32 tid<1ms TTL=64
Svar fra 148.140.26.121: byte=32 tid<1ms TTL=64
Svar fra 148.140.26.121: byte=32 tid<1ms TTL=64
```

the nmap show its listening on the port? its closed but is that because it waits for a connection?

```
root@Linux-box-kontornett:~# nmap -sT -p 22,3306 148.140.26.121

Starting Nmap 4.76 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2010-02-02 16:29 CET
Interesting ports on 148.140.26.121:
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp   open   ssh
3306/tcp closed mysql
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the ip mysql binds the port.

In my.cnf, replace

> bind-address            = 127.0.0.1

with your ip.

Comment: this was it, thx mate.